# Confusion about app.listen(port, hostname) and server.createServer()

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, hosting

I know that app.listen(port, hostname) makes the system listen for a specific socket but do I write this code in the client-side computer or server-side computer? Also server.createServer() creates a server but is this code written in the client-side computer or server-side computer?? (this confusion happened because I was localhosting and my computer was both client-side and server-side at the same time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those pieces of code go on the server-side.

Comment: so that would mean that if I write app.listen(8080, '50.50.50.1'), I will only accept a client-side user with port 8080 and IP address of  '50.50.50.1' right? but that's a little bizarre to me because usually the machine that hosts a website has hundreds if not thousands of client-side users connecting/visiting the website.... but then... using app.listen() will accept only ONE client-side user?

Comment: It's not a 1-to-1 mapping of client side to server side.  You can have 1 server-side (port 8080) with many client sides connected.  `app.listen()` listens for all connections to the specified ip/port.  Typically, you don't want to provide an IP address, just FYI.  https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: so if I see code, app.listen(8080, '50.50.50.1'), that definitely means that port8080 is the server-side right?(meaning the hosting machine has the port 8080) and that code will never appear on any "user-side computer" and only appear on "hosting computer" right?

Comment: That means that the site is being hosted on port 8080.  If a "user-side computer" connects to the hosting computer on that port, they would be able to render the contents returned by the server.

Comment: " site is being hosted on port 8080" -> so does that mean that the port8080 is the server-side end, not the client-side end? or does mean that port8080 is neither on the server-side nor client-side? sorry about asking too many questions but I'm a bit new so I'm trying to be a really clear idea.

Comment: In this context, port 8080 is on the server side.